# How to convert Binding<Error?> to Binding<Bool>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

Is there any handy way to convert `Binding<Error?>` to `Binding<Bool>`? I'm having view model that has one of the property `@published var error: Error?`. I would like to show an alert if there is an error. But `Alert` accepts only `Binding<Bool>` as a parameter.

I was able to accomplish this by using introducing another property but this seems to me like not the most efficient way.

Code with the additional property

```
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published
    var error: Error? {
        didSet {
            isError = error != nil
        }
    }

    @Published
    var isError: Bool = false
}

struct SampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: SampleViewModel

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView().alert(isPresented: $viewModel.isError) { () -> Alert in
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(viewModel.error!.localizedDescription), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Binding<Bool>.constant($viewModel.error.wrappedValue != nil)`

```
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published
    var error: Error?
}

struct SampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: SampleViewModel

    var body: some View {

        let isError = Binding<Bool>.constant($viewModel.error.wrappedValue != nil)

        return EmptyView().alert(isPresented: isError) { () -> Alert in
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(viewModel.error!.localizedDescription), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}
```